# How to load different UI for each node

Tags: corda

I am referring Cordapp example project with default UI.  I wanted to display different UI for different users. For example, one action is relevant to node A , but not to node B. How can I control it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option which I am using in my Cordapp is to first make an API call to get the nodes identity. Based on the identity of the node, you can then run different JavaScript functions and present different html pages / functionality. While this method does involve some hardcoding of node names, it works quite well for simple Proof of Concepts and demos.

Check out [this](https://github.com/raymogg/termDepositCordapp/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/main/resources/testWeb/js/angular-module.js) for an example - take a look at the displayNodeName() function.

Answer (score 0):

A CorDapp's logical boundary is pretty much the RPC layer.

With current versions of Corda, a web-server is bundled which allows you to create a RESTful API to communicate with the RPC layer. So you have complete control and flexibility in how you want to interact with the RPC layer.

As such, you should think about splitting your API into actions for node A and actions for node B and then split your front-end accordingly.

You could then set-up two different routes with each one loading a different interface.

Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/corda/LetterOfCredit) and it's corresponding front-end [project](https://github.com/corda/LetterOfCreditWeb).
There are interfaces defined for four different roles.